# How to make a bash script wait and then continue running?

Tags: linux, bash, script

I have an `.sh` script. I would like to wait 25 minutes and then continue running, NOT repeat.
It's something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/bash ~/path/script.sh
```

I want it to kill a process after waiting 25 minutes.

```
#Wait 25 minutes
killall process
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the sleep command:
`sleep 25m`

So it would look like

```
sleep 25m
killall process
```

Source and good resource: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-sleep-bash-scripting/

Answer (score 0):

Try: `sleep 25m`

This should make the script sleep for 25 minutes and then continuing executing after

For sleeping in second try: `sleep 25`

This will make it sleep for 25 seconds